# Determine at which values of $\theta$ the function $f(\theta)=\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta_1)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta_1)$ equals $1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I want to determine at which values the function $f(\theta)=\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta_1)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta_1)$ equals $1$. I was unsure about my **final step**, where I argue that I need to show that $f$ has an upper bound of $1$. If there are other approaches, please share.

My proof claims that the answer is when $\theta=\theta_1$...and due to the $2\pi$ periodicity of $f$, we really should say $\theta=\theta_1+2\pi z$ for any $z \in \mathbb Z$.

---

Take the derivative $f$ to give us $f'(\theta)=-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta_1)$. Notice that this expression is defined on all of $\mathbb R$...meaning that $f$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbb R$...which means that all of our local maximum and minimum points must have a derivative of $0$. Next, determine under what conditions $f' =0$. Equivalently, determine which values of $\theta$ produce the following expression: $\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta_1)=\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta_1)$.

To do this, we can break down this expression in to several cases:

1. $\sin(\theta_1) = 0$
2. $\cos(\theta_1) = 0$
3. $\sin(\theta_1) \neq 0$ and $\cos(\theta_1) \neq 0$

---

**Case 1:**
Suppose $\sin(\theta_1) = 0$. Then $\cos(\theta_1)=0$ or $\sin(\theta)=0$. Clearly, $\cos(\theta_1) \neq 0$ because no such value of $\theta$ has a $\sin$ value of $0$ and $\cos$ value of $0$ simultaneously $\color{red}{(\dagger)}$: so $\sin(\theta)=0$. This means that $\theta = 0\pm 2\pi n$ or $\theta = \pi \pm 2\pi n$.

**Case 2:** A similar argument will show that we must have $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2} \pm 2\pi n$ or $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2} \pm 2\pi n$.

**Case 3:** Suppose $\sin(\theta_1) \neq 0$ and $\cos(\theta_1) \neq 0$. In this case, we write our expression as:

$$\sin(\theta)=\cos(\theta)\cdot \frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{\cos(\theta_1)}$$

We can quickly rule out the subcases of i) $\sin(\theta)=0$ and ii) $\cos(\theta)=0$. Otherwise, we will have a similar contradiction as the point raised for $\color{red}{(\dagger)}$. So we must have $\sin(\theta) \neq 0$ **and** $\cos(\theta)\neq 0$. Therefore, we can rewrite our equation as:

\begin{align}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}&=\frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{\cos(\theta_1)} \\ \tan(\theta)&=\tan(\theta_1)\end{align}

The $\tan$ function oscillates at a period of $\pi$. Therefore $\theta=\theta_1 \pm \pi n$.

---

For each case, we will plug in our values of $\theta$ to determine which $\theta$ values correspond to local maximums and local minimums. Because of the $2\pi$ periodicity of $\cos$ and $\sin$, we will only consider the the interval $[0,2\pi)$. Also, note that if $\sin(\theta_1)=0$, then $\theta_1=0$ or $\pi$. Similarly, if $\cos(\theta_1)=0$, then $\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

**Case 1**

Conditions: $\theta=0$, $\theta_1=0$ . Therefore $f\left(0\right)=1$

Conditions: $\theta=0$, $\theta_1=\pi$ . Therefore $f\left(0\right)=-1$

Conditions: $\theta=\pi$, $\theta_1=0$. Therefore $f\left(\pi\right)=-1$

Conditions: $\theta=\pi$, $\theta_1=\pi$. Therefore $f\left(\pi\right)=1$

**Case 2**

Conditions: $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$

Conditions: $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\theta_1=\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Therefore $f\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=-1$

Conditions: $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-1$

Conditions: $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\theta_1=\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Therefore $f\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=1$

**Case 3** Recall that $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos(x)$

Conditions: $\theta=\theta_1$, $\cos(\theta_1)\neq 0$, $\sin(\theta_1)\neq 0$. Therefore $f(\theta)=1$

Conditions: $\theta=\theta_1+\pi$, $\cos(\theta_1)\neq 0$, $\sin(\theta_1)\neq 0$. Therefore $f(\theta+\pi)=-1$

---

Across all cases, we see that $1$ is a local maximum value, and this is achieved when $\theta=\theta_1$. If I can show that $1$ is an upper bound for $f$, then we can conclude that $\theta=\theta_1$ is the only value for which $f(\theta)=1$.

Firstly, clearly an upper bound exists because $-1 \leq \cos(\theta)\cos(\theta_1) \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq \sin(\theta)\sin(\theta_1) \leq 1$, which means that $|\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta_1)|+|\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta_1)| \leq 2$. By the triangle inequality theorem, we must then have that $|\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta_1)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta_1)|\leq 2$, which implies that for any $\theta \in \mathbb R$: $f(\theta) \leq 2$.

Next, it is easy to demonstrate that $f$ is periodic over $2\pi$: $f(\theta)=f(\theta+2\pi)$. This means that for any arbitrary closed interval that is $2\pi$ long, all of the image of $f$ must be contained in this interval.

Now, suppose by contradiction that $1$ is the not the maximum value of $f$. Consider any arbitrary interval $[a,b]$ such that $|b-a|=2\pi$. Because $f$ is continuous, a maximum value $f(\theta_{max}) \gt 1$ must be attained. But $f$ is a differentiable function on all of $\mathbb R$, which means that $\theta_{\max}$ must satisfy the following: $f'(\theta_{\max})=0$. However, from our previous work, we saw that the only $\theta$s that correspond to $f'(\theta)=0$ are ones where $f(\theta)=\pm 1$. However, we have assumed that $f(\theta_{max}) \gt 1$. Contradiction.

Therefore $1$ must be the maximum value of $f$. In particular, then, we must have that $\theta=\theta_1$ is the only condition under which $\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta_1)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta_1)=1$.

Comment: $f(\theta)=\cos (\theta-\theta_1)$ so there is a one line answer.

Comment: There's not only one solution. For example, $\theta = \theta_1 + 2\pi$ is another one.

Comment: @jjagmath Well...I mean $\theta=\theta_1+2\pi z$ for any $z \in \mathbb Z$, sure. I figured that was trivially assumed - due to the $2\pi$ periodicity of the function.

Comment: But you stated very clearly "is precisely (and only) when $\theta = \theta_1$", and "we must have that $\theta = \theta_1$ is the only condition under which..."

Comment: Similarly $f'(\theta)=-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta_1)=-\sin(\theta-\theta_1)$ and the zeros are easily found to tell you where there are maxima and minima

Comment: @jjagmath ahhh - good point. Thank you. I'll change it up.

Answer (score -1):

Observe that ${\displaystyle \cos(x\pm y)=\cos x\cdot \cos y\mp \sin x\cdot \sin y}$ so you have $\cos(\theta_1-\theta)\leq1$
and you don't need your proof (which I did not follow)